Broken AVD path
I'm trying to launch Android emulator in a docker container on CI. I have setup plenty of env variables:
# Install Android SDK
ENV ANDROID_HOME      /usr/local/android-sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_HOME  ${ANDROID_HOME}
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT  ${ANDROID_HOME}
ENV ANDROID_SDK       ${ANDROID_HOME}

Also all necessary dependencies are installed:
RUN sdkmanager --update --sdk_root="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" && sdkmanager --sdk_root="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" \
        "build-tools;33.0.2" \
        "platforms;android-33" \
        "platform-tools" \
        "emulator" \
        "system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64"

And made sure that structure of the folders is the following:
/usr/local/android-sdk
|- build-tools
|- cmdline-tools
|- emulator
|- licenses
|- platforms
|- platform-tools
|- system-images

I could create an avd, using the avdmanager echo no | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64". However, while it is created a number of warnings like this is spawned:

Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;33.0.2' in inconsistent location '/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.2' (Expected '/usr/local/build-tools/33.0.2')

And when I try to launch the created AVD via the emulator -verbose -show-kernel -avd test  command it fails:
WARNING | /usr/local/android-sdk/android-sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64/ is not a valid directory.
WARNING | emulator has searched the above paths but found no valid sdk root directory.
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/usr/local/android-sdk]!
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-unknown/emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 108
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
DEBUG   | Current emulator version 34.2.16 is the same as the required version 34.2.16.
INFO    | Found AVD name 'test'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: '/usr/local/android-sdk/emulator'
INFO    | AVD test has path /usr/local/android-sdk/.android/avd/../avd/test.avd
INFO    | trying to check whether /usr/local/android-sdk is a valid sdk root

Obvously, because it tries to find image in /usr/local/android-sdk/android-sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64/ location, which doesn't exist.
But WHY does it try to look for it there, if my ANDROID_HOME is correctly set to /usr/local/android-sdk? Why does it try to look at the /usr/local/android-sdk/android-sdk path?
And on the other hand, why does avdmanager expects the root to be /usr/local, not /usr/local/android-sdk?
